# django loaddata insists on reading xml fixture as ascii - need to read as utf-8

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, python-unicode

I'm using loaddata to reload a fixture (for some reason the data in the database seems to have become corrupt). Doing results in an error which indicates that `loaddata` is treating the xml as ascii. It is in fact UTF-8, which is causing the error:

```
$ python manage.py loaddata --traceback ./countries/fixtures/initial_data.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcintustin/oneclickrep/oneclickcosvirt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 202, in handle
    'error_msg': e
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

(Increasing the verbosity just tells me about where it's looking for fixtures. There is no more information to be had. This is the complete stacktrace as provided by `loaddata`).

The fixture begins:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<django-objects version="1.0">
    <object pk="AF" model="countries.country">
        <field type="CharField" name="name">AFGHANISTAN</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="printable_name">Afghanistan</field>
        <field type="CharField" name="iso3">AFG</field>
        <field type="PositiveSmallIntegerField" name="numcode">4</field>
    </object>
<!-- rest of file -->
</django-objects>
```

It declares itself to be utf-8, and it is utf-8 (I resaved it as utf-8 using emacs, just to be sure).

The problem here is not that my input is utf-8, but that `loaddata` wants to treat it as something else. How can I force `loaddata` to decode it right? Or alternatively, how easy is it to invoke the `loaddata` stuff programmatically, after I have manually loaded my xml into a unicode string?

Using django 1.4 on linux, with sqlite as the database backend.

Answer (score 1):

While you can invoke `loaddata` programmatically via `call_command` from `django.core.management`, it doesn't look like there are options to set an encoding or a string input.  So when you invoke it, you'll still pass the same file and it will run into the same issue.

One option would be to create your own loaddata that has a parameter for encoding.  You can copy the default [`loaddata` command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py) and add a few lines to do the encoding.  It seem the relevant line where you want to start is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py#L166).